# How to get the name of an Excel sheet that is written with special characters, using R?

Tags: r, excel

I am using the package `xlsx` to read and save the existing names of Excel sheets.

```r
require(xlsx)

myworkbook <- loadWorkbook("myfile.xlsx")

list_of_sheets_names <- names(getSheets(myworkbook))
```

The problem that I have is that many of the names are written using special characters. I haven't had this problem when reading the **content** of the sheets, since I can - with the function `read.xlsx` - specify the encoding:

```r
mydataframe <- read.xlsx(myfile, sheetIndex = 1, header = FALSE,
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

But this function retrieves data only from the cells of the sheet, it does not retrieve the name of Excel sheets.

Do you know any way in which I could use R to read the name of an Excel sheet specifying that it is encoded as UTF-8?

I don't need to use `xlsx` necessarily, I am open to other packages.

Comment: Have you tried `readxl::excel_sheets()`?

Comment: @YifuYan Thank you. `readxl::excel_sheets()` does exactly what I needed. It gives me a list with the names of the sheets and the special caracters are correctly encoded.